# In Firestore, how do you query a range of numbers for items that have a range of numbers

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to figure out in firestore what the best way is to query date data for a week. I have objects that span multiples days and i want to know what elements are a part of a particular time span.  Right now my data hasa start and end date represented by their unix ms value. Some start before the query start date and some end After the query end date. How am I to properly query this or properly denormalize the data.

For example i want to retrieve all items that occur for this current month, Oct. Some elements might have a start date of Sept 30 - Oct 2 and some might be Oct 31 - Nov 2nd.  How do i structure/query my data to include those edge cases?

```
 {
  active: true,
  address: {
    addressLine1: "5 May Way",
    city: "Wilmington",
    state: "Ny",
    zip: "40778"
  },
  createdOn: 1570558984758,
  day: 1570507200000,
  event: {
    startDate: 1570558945155,
    endDate: 1570559945160,
    utcOffset: -240
  },
  id: "6FXSCc8BFqww59PT0HyE",
  name: "Test",
  portalId: "iHvdmHxsQsQvoaQIO0r4",
  statusId: 0,
}
```

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head, you may include a field for the months that event happen in (e.g. `occurrence`). This field would be an array and your query to find out if that event happened in a specific month you could use a `where` clause where that field would contain the month you are looking for. Something like `where('occurrence', 'array-contains', 'October')`.

That is, you could add to your `event` field the array `occurrence`, it would look like this:

```
event: {
    startDate: xxxxxxxxx,
    endDate: xxxxxxxxx,
    utcOffset: xxx,
    ocurrence: [September, October]
}
```

This would handle both regular and edge cases.